# How to print .NET String.Format space character on a regular string?

Tags: c#, string, .net-core

I am working on strings in .Net Core. I have a string formatted using `:n` and when it is formatted the output is `123 456,00`. I wanted to assert that the formatted string is equal to the string i wish it to be but i get an `Assert.Equal Failure()` and the problem is in the space character. In the output it asserts that the two spaces are different.

Here is my code :

```
public void Separator()
{
    var str = string.Format("{0:n}", 123456);
    Assert.Equal("123 456,00",str);
}
```

I also compared the space character from the formatted string to a regular space character with an assert as follows `Assert.Equal(' ',str[3]);`i get that the expected value is `0x00a`.

Why is this happening and how can i get the same character without using `string.Format()`?

Comment: Do you want to say that `Assert.Equal()` says `123 456,00` is not equal to `123 456,00`? Then you need to check the exact values in some hex editor. Or just use some online tool to see if there is no typo. Try http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/

Comment: yes i get a difference in (pos 3) meaning the two spaces are not equal.

Comment: Are you sure the spaces are identical? Check at http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/

Comment: Which culture are you using here?

Comment: they are not identical that is my question, how can i print the same space without using string.Format() ?

Comment: I asked because all the numbers in your question contain identical spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culture you are using specifies that the number group separator is a different ASCII character than space. I'm guessing you are using `ru-RU` here, which means the digit is ASCII character 160, which means those strings will not match if you have just typed a space.

You could replace the space with the culture's separator like this for example:

```
var currentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
var stringToCompare = "123 456,00".Replace(
    " ", 
    currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator);

Assert.Equal(stringToCompare, str);
```

Comment: Interesting, a NO-BREAK SPACE in a number is much more appropriate than a normal space. Nit pick: Characters in .NET are Unicode, not ASCII. NO-BREAK SPACE has one UTF-16 code unit, with the value '\u00a0' (160).